# Jenkins git plugin error on configure page

Tags: jenkins

We're running into a problem creating our very first job on a newly installed Jenkins 1.532.2, with Jenkins Git plugin 2.0.2, Jenkins Git client plugin 1.6.3, and GitHub plugin 1.8.

The error I see on the "new job" page is just below the "Git Repositories" radio button in the Source Code Management section:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: 
jar:file:/var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/jenkins-core-1.532.2.jar!/lib/form/repeatableProperty.jelly:66:69:
<st:include> No such property: lib for class: hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig.config
```

Interestingly, I see no errors in the log file at all.

Any ideas how to diagnosis this error?

Answer (score 1):

I never did find the cause, but the problem went away by reverting the git plugin and git client plugin to 1.5 and 1.0.7 respectively, as suggested in https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20533

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been reported as https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-22649
1.532.3 LTS don't suffer this issue, as new LTS branch. Not sure about the root cause, looks like a strange classloader conflict.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. I am using git-client 1.12.0, git 2.3.1 and matrix project plugin 1.4 fixed the issue.

Follow this for more information.

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-24582

Hope this helps.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20533 once you enable/install the matrix plugin, I am not seeing this error